# powershell string comparison error

Tags: validation, powershell, operators

I'm comparing 2 strings stored in a variable and validating them against a couple of conditions. See Code Below:

```
do
    {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor 'Yellow' "Enter Users Password `nMust be 8 or more characters long and contain a UPPER case character and a Digit."
    $Password = Read-Host "First time" -AsSecureString
    $Passcheck = Read-Host "And again" -AsSecureString

    $PassConvertFirst = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringtoBSTR($Password) ; $PlainPass1 = [system.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($passconvertfirst)
    $PassConvertSecond = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringtoBSTR($Passcheck) ; $PlainPass2 = [system.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($Passconvertsecond)

    if ($PlainPass1 -Contains $PlainPass2 -and $PlainPass1.Length -ge 8 -or $PlainPass2.Length -ge 8)
    {
        $PassCheckBreak = $false
        $PlainPassword = $PlainPass2
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Warning "Passwords don't match, Try again.."
        $PassCheckBreak = $true

    }
}
while ($PassCheckBreak)
```

While this works 99.99% of the time i'm coming across a weird error when I try and compare this:

P4ssw0rd with P4ssword

Using the code above this gets validated as true! which makes no sense as if I try validating

W0rd with word

It fails validation.

I've tried changing to a comparative operator and I'm still getting the same issue.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Many Thanks, 
Nigel Tatschner

Comment: Did you echo the `$PlainPass` variables to see what they actually are? You also need to read this: http://windowsitpro.com/blog/powershell-contains. `-contains` is not suitable for what you're attempting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is within the `if` statement.

Let's have a closer look:

```
$PlainPass1 -Contains $PlainPass2 -and $PlainPass1.Length -ge 8 -or $PlainPass2.Length -ge 8
```

Evaluate each comparision:

```
$PlainPass1 -Contains $PlainPass2 # False
$PlainPass1.Length -ge 8 # True
$PlainPass2.Length -ge 8 #true
```

Thus the outcome is:

```
$false -and $true -or $true
```

Anything `-or $true` is true. Lesson: mind the binding order. When in doubt, use parenthesis.

Comment: Don't forget what @arco444 was saying about `-contains`. He is actually looking for `-match` or `-like`